# Eigenvalue inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $M$ a symmetric, invertible 3x3 matrix with positive elements and positive eigenvalues $(a,b,b)\geq 0.$ Can we write the following inequality?
\begin{equation}
\forall u\in\mathbb{R}^3,~\min(a,b)u^Tu \leq u^TMu \leq \max(a,b)u^Tu.
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. In the general case, let $M\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be real symmetric. Therefore, it has $n$ real eigenvalues and let $\lambda_1\ge\lambda_2\ge\ldots\ge\lambda_n$.

The eigenvectors $v_i$, $i=1,\ldots,n$, associated with the eigenvalue $\lambda_i$, $i=1,\ldots,n$, are such that $v_i^Tv_j=1$ if $i=j$ and 0 otherwise.

Now pick $u\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $u^Tu=1$. Then, $u$ can be expressed on the orthogonal basis $(v_1,\ldots,v_n)$ as $u=\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_iv_i$ where $\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_i^2=1$ since $u^Tu=1$.

Now, we can see that

$$u^TMu=\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_iv_i\right)^TM\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_iv_i\right)=\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_iv_i\right)^T\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_iMv_i\right)=\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_iv_i\right)^T\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_i\lambda_iv_i\right)
$$
and, therefore, using the fact that $v_i^Tv_j=1$ if $i=j$ and 0 otherwise, we obtain
$$u^TMu=\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_i^2\lambda_i.
$$

So, we can see that the maximum over all $\alpha_i$'s such that $\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_i^2=1$ is $\lambda_1$ and the minimum is $\lambda_n$.

This yields that $$\lambda_n\le u^TMu\le \lambda_1,\ \mathrm{for\ all }\ u\in\mathbb{R}^n,\ u^Tu=1.$$

When $u^Tu\ne1$, the statement simply becomes
$$\lambda_nu^Tu\le u^TMu\le \lambda_1u^Tu,\ \mathrm{for\ all }\ u\in\mathbb{R}^n.$$